# How come the static variable is Serialized?

Tags: java, serialization, static-members

```
public class MySerializable implements Serializable{

    private int x=10;
    private static int y = 15;
    public static void main(String...args){
        AnotherClass a = new AnotherClass();
        AnotherClass b;
        //Serialize
        try {
            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("MyFile.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream Oout = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
            Oout.writeObject(a);
            System.out.println( a.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //De-serialize
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("MyFile.ser");
            ObjectInputStream  Oin = new ObjectInputStream (fis); 
            b = (AnotherClass) Oin.readObject();
            System.out.println( b.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

class AnotherClass  implements Serializable{  

    transient int x = 8;  
    static int y = 9;  

    @Override  
    public String toString() {  
        return "x : " + x + ", y :" + y;  
    }  
}
```

Can you please tell me how the static variable is serialized  ??

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, static variables can be serialized (But you should not do that), since **serialization** is the process of **saving the state** of an *instance* of a class, and static variables are common to all instances. They don't say anything about the instance's state, so, it wouldn't make sense at all.

Suppose you were allowed to serialize a static variable. Then, when you deserialize the instance, you will be getting an old copy of that variable, which might have been changed since then. Since the static variable is shared across all instances of the class, a change in the variable from any instance must be reflected in this instance.

So, they should not be serialized, because the variable under these conditions could possibly violate its contract as a static variable.

**Serialization**: -

- Should not serialize the static variables..

**Deserialization**: -

- Instance will get the static fields that was loaded with the class.. So, any changes that might have been done for that variable will be liable for this instance also..

Comment: This answer is not correct, the static variable is not being stored and restored by serialization. Static variables cannot and are not serialized; the value of the static field stays in the class field the entire time...it never left memory at all.

Answer (score 2):

The Current output of MySerializable Class is below

```
x : 8, y :9
x : 0, y :9
```

In this case the static variable are getting printed after calling **toString() method**, by this time it will reads value from class level variable.

Try this:

Add this line of code in MySerializable Class after `//Serialize` block

```
AnotherClass.y = 5;
```

the output is :

```
x : 8, y :9
x : 0, y :5
```

this means the static variable is not storing in the file, it will read dynammically by toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

**-** `Serialization` is used to save the **state of the object** during serialization, so during the de-serialization the saved state can be used in order to resurrect an Identical object on the heap.

**-**  **Yes** `static` variable can be `serialized` but it **doesn't make any sense**.....

Answer (score 0):

Static variables cannot be and are not serialized.

Your question seems to be based on the fact that you're seeing the same value from the static variable after serialization as before serialization, but this is not due to the value being serialized and restored.

This behavior is because the static initializer for that static variable sets it to 9, and it is never changed.

To verify that static variables are not serialized, you can either perform NPKR's suggested change, modifying the static field between serialization and deserialization, or you could do the following:

Run this program, then comment out the bit that performs the serialization. You'll have the old serialized version on disk as a result.

Then change the static initializer of the static field to `y = 5`, and run the program again: you'll get 'x: 0 y: 5`as the output, because the value`9` of the static field was not restored.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

class TestJava implements Serializable{
    public static int k = 10;
    public int j=5;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    TestJava tj1= new TestJava();
    TestJava tj2;
    
    
        try{ //serialization
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("myclass.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(tj1);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
            System.out.println("object serielized 1..."+tj1.j);
            System.out.println("object serielized 2..."+tj1.k);
            System.out.println("object serielized 3..."+k);
            k=++k; // 'k' value incrementd after serialization
          } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
             fnfe.printStackTrace();
          } catch(IOException ioex){
             ioex.printStackTrace();
          }
    
      
          try{ //deserialization
              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myclass.ser");
              ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
              tj2 = (TestJava) ois.readObject();
              ois.close();
              fis.close();
              System.out.println("object DEEEEserielized 1..."+tj2.j);
              System.out.println("object DEEEEserielized 2..."+tj2.k); 
              System.out.println("object DEEEEserielized 3..."+k); 
            // in deserialization 'k' value is shown as incremented. 
            // That means Static varialbe 'K' is not serialized.
            // if 'K' value is serialized then, it has to show old value before incrementd the 'K' value.
            } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
              fnfe.printStackTrace();
            } catch(IOException ioex){
              ioex.printStackTrace();
            } catch(ClassNotFoundException CNFE){
              CNFE.printStackTrace();                   
           }
      }
}

/* Output of the above program
 
object serielized 1...5
object serielized 2...10
object serielized 3...10
object DEEEEserielized 1...5
object DEEEEserielized 2...11
object DEEEEserielized 3...11


*/
```